# What's the point in fetching remote data in componentDidMount method if it will cause change in what is shown to user?

Tags: reactjs, render, paint, react-hooks

You are right that there are too much words. The only remaining question now is:

Why is it considered to be normal to fetch data in `cDM` method if it is called after rendering and will cause an extra re-rendering and re-drawing after data has been fetched? More to it - user will see screen flickering.

---

I've spent two hours reading SO and other articles and still have questions. I'd like to get a better grasp of things and reassure them that my understanding is correct.

It all started with learning hooks and thinking about the difference between `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect`. I learnt that `useEffect` should be used when things which it does don't affect what is shown to user (some background job) and `useLayoutEffect` is fired "synchronously before painting" - so, for example, should be used when I want to show a list on screen and data for it is fetched form somewhere else. Thus, if I fetch data in `useLayoutEffect` it will fetch the data first, and only after that update state and show the screen with that data to the user. If I used `useEffect` it would show to the user an empty list first (because it is asynchronous and doesn't stop painting) and then re-paint it after data is received. Confusing part is that it says that `useLayoutEffect`, the same as `useEffect`, is called after the rendering has finished. I explain why it doesn't make any sense to me in the last paragraph.

Another confusing thing is that it says that `useEffect` should be used in the same place where `cDM` or `cDU` methods are called. But I've been fetching data in `cDM` method since I started using react.
Does it mean that I did it wrong all the time? Because I should have done it where `useLayoutEffect` is fired. And this brings me to the next paragraph.

The most confusing thing - a relationship between rendering, painting and `cDM` method. It says that `cDM` is called after the rendering has finished. It also says that "rendering has finished" means that DOM, layout, sizes, styles - everything is calculated and ready to be painted by the browser. I understand it in a way that at this point it makes no sense to do anything that would change what is shown to a user - because it is all already calculated! Shouldn't there be a hook that is called before rendering? For example, I call this hook to fetch data for some list which is shown on screen. Only after data is fetched rendering should occur because now react knows how many elements are on the list and how much space will it take and so on. I mean what's a point in making rendering before you know all your data? Isn't react forced to recalculate everything after data is fetched?

I really hope you will help me to understand these things. Thank you.

Comment: Please use backtick character around methods / code so that is easier to read. It can make `useLayoutEffect` easier to notice as method in larger paragraphs

Comment: Sorry. I've updated it.

Comment: if it will help: https://daveceddia.com/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect/

Comment: Not really sure why my comment was removed, but comparing hooks to class life cycle methods is the wrong way to think about hooks. Period.

Comment: it is not about react hooks really. I am more concerned whether I understand things in general correctly. So far none confirmed/corrected me.

Comment: 1/2 @user6419217 it is extremely difficult to see what your question is. In short yes, it appears you understand the difference between useEffect and useLayoutEffect.. 99% of the time you should use useEffect. If you're fetching data during mount, and want to show a user a loading spinner, useEffect lets you do this. You then go on to compare useEffect to cDM/cDU, which they are not apples to apples. You can "simulate" cDM/cDU with useEffect but that doesn't make them the same. useEffect will run depending upon the dependency array. So, useEffect syncs with a piece of state...

Comment: 2/2 ...whichever piece of state you put in the dependency array, useEffect will run when that state changes. You have been fetching data correctly in cDM.. If you could be more specific or provide examples on what you are confused about, versus writing 3 paragraphs with multiple questions strewn about, people would be able to help you more effectively.

Comment: Hello Matt. Thanks for comments. The only remaining question for me now is why it's considered to be normal to fetch data in cDM method if it is called after rendering and will cause an extra re-rendering and re-drawing after data has been fetched? More to it - user will see screen flickering.